# Overriding in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, class, overriding

I want to be able to do the following

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def Create(self):
        return 'Password'

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Create()
    def Create(self):
        return 'The '+self.Create #I want to return 'The Password'
```

I would like to get a parent function from a child class in a function that is overriding it. I am not sure how to do this.

This is a little hard to explain, comment if you are having trouble understanding.

Edit:

Thanks for the answers everyone, I almost thought that this was impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The `super()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) is meant for cases like this. However, it only works on "new-style" classes, so you'll need to modify your definition of `Parent` to inherit from `object` as well (you should always be using "new-style" classes, anyway).

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def Create(self):
        return 'Password'

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Create()
    def Create(self):
        return 'The ' + super(Child, self).Create()


print Child().Create() # prints "The Password"
```

Comment: Ohh Nice,  I thought I could only use that in the __init__ but I guess not

Answer (score 7):

Either refer to the parent explicitly or (in new-style classes) use [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super).

```
class Child(Parent):
   ...
  def Create(self):
    return 'The ' + Parent.Create(self)
```

Comment: good call, the OP is not using new style classes in python versions < 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as referring to the base class via [super](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super):

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Create()
    def Create(self):
        return 'The '+ super(Child, self).Create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `super` function to access the parent `super(Child,self).create()` to call create from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"super()"** to call **the super class method "Create()"** as shown below:

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def Create(self):
        return 'Password'

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Create()
    def Create(self):   # Here
        return 'The ' + super().Create()
        
print(Child().Create()) # The Password
```